# How to define ranges for integer/decimal/float fields in D7?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I would like to add an **integer/decimal/float field** to a content type where users can define **ranges** for these numbers as two separate fields.
Like when adding a [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) field, and being able to add an end date as a separate field with a little checkbox:

[image: Date field ranges] (So the output will be like this: `2011 - 2012`.)

Use case: users would like to define approximate numbers, they don't know data exactly, for example:

*Stream bed's average depth*: `0.3 m` - `1 m`
*Stream bed's average width*: `1 m` - `2 m`

(`m` would only be a suffix)
etc.

Comment: If you're using Drupal 6 there's the [range](http://drupal.org/project/range) and [measured value field](http://drupal.org/project/mvf) modules...I haven't seen anything similar for Drupal 7

Comment: @Clive: oh, sorry (and thanks), I forgot to mention I'm using D7... added it to tags. I'm sorry to hear that there are no modules to do that (or we just haven't found any of them yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed the same functionality for a project I am working on.

I have created a sandbox project http://drupal.org/sandbox/thepearson/1842424 which I'll be working on hopefully releasing as contrib. I still need to do some more testing, tidy up and documentation.

Obviously it's in sandbox so, use at your own risk. Currently supports `int` and `float`. Supports defining min and max limits on both start and end values along with prefix, suffix and range indicator. ie:

```
[prefix] [min] [indicator] [max] [suffix]
[$ ]     [123] [<----->]   [157] [per person]
```

alnum type is there but limit validation seems a bit buggy. I would recommend not using alnum until more testing is done.

It's also supports some `hook_info`/`hook_info_alter` functions for you to either define your own range datatypes, or change the existing ones. Look at the sub-module `range_integer` to see how it's done.

If you find any bugs please raise bug reports at [drupal.org](http://www.drupal.org).

Comment: wow, thank you very much! This is a really good initiative, I just tried it, and it seems like a really good start. I will provide infos about the bugs I experienced and suggestions I found out when testing. ;) Thanks again! Voted up and accepted!

Comment: How do I install and use it? Sorry but am novice.

Comment: @Raj - take look at [this](http://drupal.org/node/1294804) which should help as a git/sandbox primer. Clone the repo into a site module folder and then enable it via your modules screen. If Fields UI module is turned on you can then add a "Range" field to any content type.

Comment: @Raj: on Windows, you should install [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/), start Git Shell (from the Start menu), and run `git clone http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/thepearson/1842424.git ranges`. After that, you can copy the downloaded `ranges` folder to your `sites/all/modules` directory.

Comment: I am aware of and use Git, am novice at Drupal though ;) I will place the same in modules folder of site. When are you planning for a full featured release of the same? Thanks for this feature! Actually I cant believe that there is no support for range type of fields!

Comment: Tested it, great effort by @thepearson (y) It works for the minimal requirement which I have for integers. The only thing needed is validation for the values entered by users, range start should always be lesser than range end. Thanks.

Comment: And one more feature would be great. As soon as user starts filling the minimum value text field, the maximum value should be auto-filled with the same minimum value. This should happen only if the other field is nil.

Comment: @thepearson I am facing some errors, I have posted it in the drupal bug report: http://drupal.org/node/1848144 Please check it and update the status :) Thanks

Comment: @Raj: _"As soon as user starts filling the minimum value text field, the maximum value should be auto-filled with the same minimum value."_ I think this is a special use-case of yours, which could easily be implemented in your own module's or theme's JS file with binding an event handler to [`.keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/). Btw., feature requests should be posted on drupal.org's issue queue. :)

Comment: Ok, I am new in PHP programming. I will definitely try and provide the feature with guidance :) So shall I raise a request for this feature in drupal.org? Thanks.

Comment: @Raj: I think this should be implemented in your own custom module, not in the Ranges module, because it can be an individual need which can be solved in some lines of JavaScript codes. But the developer decides. :)

Comment: @thepearson: have you seen Shevchuk's [answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/60371/2368)? There's another sandbox module called Range field. I raised an issue to possibly merge the two modules: http://drupal.org/node/1912804. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Taran2l's Range field module](https://drupal.org/sandbox/Taran2L/1848632), which already passed [module review](https://drupal.org/node/1848868) and is now on its way on taking over [Range](https://drupal.org/project/range) project (which is stuck on 6.x version and seems to be abandoned). It would be nice if @thepearson collaborated with the author of this module.

UPD: Taran2l is [now official owner](https://drupal.org/node/1877762#comment-7043636) of the [Range](https://drupal.org/project/range) project.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, thanks! I agree that it would be great to merge the two modules, and for the two developers to help each other's efforts.